# How to ignore whitespace in github when comparing?

Tags: github

I have committed a file after prettifying it in sublime. Now when I am comparing the differences in GitHub web UI it's showing a lot of changes, so it is very difficult to see the actual changes. Can I compare files in there and ignore the whitespace?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

On github, you simply append the `w=1` parameter to the URL for it to ignore whitespace.

That would look something like:

```
https://github.com/account_name/repo/pull/14/files?w=1
```

Comment: but in this, we have to add a parameter everytime. Can't we do something while pushing the code or while adding or commiting the file ?

Comment: When I view multiple files in a pull request I'm creating, adding ?w=1 appears to do nothing.

Comment: if there is already get params has initiated then add &w=1 at the end of URL

Comment: Is there anyway to make this default behaviour for my profile?

Comment: Very nice for a PR. How about a simple compare between a release and master: https://github.com/account_name/compare/v1.0?w=1

Answer (score 70):

Since Oct. 2021, this option is now persistent!

> ### [Hiding whitespace is now remembered for each pull request](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-14-hiding-whitespace-is-now-remembered-for-each-pull-request/)
>
> The diff setting to hide whitespace changes in the pull request Files Changed tab is now remembered for you for that pull request.
>
> You no longer need to re-enable it when you switch to another tab or when you come back to the same pull request later.
>
> [image: https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/2503052/137387087-91cc8458-9e11-44a9-8da0-f48251ec452c.gif?ssl=1 -- hide-whitespace2]
>
> Learn more about reviewing proposed changes in a pull request.

As noted in "[Allow users to set "Hide whitespace changes" by default #5486](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/5486#discussioncomment-4932719)", this is not a satisfying solution:

> - This impacts every Go project, as Go's standard formatter (which pretty much everyone uses) enforces consistent whitespace.
> - For those who go through a lot of PRs, most of the time merge them without requesting changes, the per-PR setting is not nearly as helpful as a repo-level or user-level setting. Please add those.
> - I'm usually only opening each PR once, so this is completely useless.
> - I review a lot of PRs and only go there once, having to click navigate and make 3 clicks to 'hide whitespace' on each and every single PR is not solved by that 'partial addressing'.

That is why you have:

- "[**Github Whitespace Disabler**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-whitespace-disabler)" for Firefox
- "**[Git Well Soon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/git-well-soon/ehpeaofieafibmhiagianfjjblpnmbdo)**" for Chrome (although the [permissions might be too broad](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/5486#discussioncomment-6443243)), mentioned in [discussion 65597](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/65597#discussioncomment-8410813)

---

[Since May 2018](https://blog.github.com/2018-05-01-ignore-white-space-in-code-review/), this option is now more visible:

> A diff view with reduced white space has been available since 2011 by adding `?w=1` to the URL.
> The new button builds on this view to better support your existing workflows.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/602352/39442176-66700966-4c7e-11e8-91a9-a71db12eeac7.png]

Select the new option "**`Hide whitespace changes`**" in that "**`Diff settings`**" new button, and you will see only the relevant changes you want.

Note: since 2018, that setting has been relocated to the setting "gear" symbol:

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/diff-settings-menu.png]

Comment: Is there any ways of maybe this change permanent from user settings or with a browser extension?

Comment: @zeachco Once I select Unified or Split, it will apply to all repos, across web sessions.

Comment: It's weird it does not for me, that's why I was wondering if it was a profile setting or an A-B test ui feature in github

Comment: It's OS independent (tried OSX, Debian-Mint, Win10).
Chrome is the browser i use, I just tried with Safari too (and no plugins) and I get the same result

Comment: @zeachco Maybe this is an option in your GitHub profile settings?

Comment: Does not appear in the `/compare/foo...bar`-style URLs.

Comment: As of Dec 2022, it looks like the UI is different than it was in Oct 2021, the file layout is moved to the side but I cannot find the diff viewer settings: 
https://i.imgur.com/s1yLXwJ.png
(the other settings wheel is for the repo settings, not the diff viewer). Does anyone know how if there is still a way to do this in the UI without manually adding w=1 to the URI?

Comment: @scholtes True, this is at PR level only now (https://github.com/community/community/discussions/5486)

Comment: This answer deserves more votes, if for no other reason but linking the browser extension.

Answer (score 9):

`git diff -w` (alternately `git diff --ignore-all-space`) ignores whitespace. You can also add `--ignore-blank-lines` if there are a lot of those.

For more details and many more options, check out [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: Also you can add this to your `.gitignore` and never worry about it again:
`[alias]
     diff = diff --ignore-space-change
`

Comment: But the question was about the Web UI.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chrome plugin [**GitHub Whitespace** by jackchuka](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-whitespace/fnpkdafamnbjoldglihkjjdicofghccm) that appends `?w=1` to the PR URLs so whitespace is always turned off

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Anthony and @Alan P's answer, here is a small bookmarklet for those that can't install chrome extensions:

```
javascript:document.location+="?w=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the used prettifier or formatter, simply hiding whitespace changes may not be enough to get rid of all style changes. Many tools add line breaks or slightly adjust the code to match a specific code style. In this case, you need a semantic diff, a special diff tool that parses the code and filters out irrelevant changes.

There are a few options, such as [difftastic](https://github.com/Wilfred/difftastic) or [diffsitter](https://github.com/afnanenayet/diffsitter), but they require you to check out the changes locally and run their tools in the terminal. The only tool I know of that works directly with GitHub is the one I am currently working on. So, disclaimer: The following part is about my own tool, SemanticDiff.

You can see SemanticDiff in action if you view the same reformat commit on  [GitHub](https://github.com/strisunshinewentingwang/pytorch/commit/6565f3dcc7b6d0a6fb6c52b293821911c71a9420?w=1) and my [diff viewer](https://app.semanticdiff.com/strisunshinewentingwang/pytorch/commit/6565f3dcc7b6d0a6fb6c52b293821911c71a9420/#torch/ao/quantization/quantize.py). The only changes that are still shown are whitespace changes inside doc strings as they *technically* modify the program. If you are you are working with public PRs/commits, you can try it out by simply pasting the corresponding GitHub URL at https://app.semanticdiff.com