# Why is github highlighting all my code to red/green even though nothing was changed?

Tags: github, pull-request

A picture says it all (note: hide whitespace changes enabled)

[image]

Someone submitted a pull request to me, and when I'm trying to review the changes, github simply says all my original code was deleted, and was replaced by the same exact code.

I develop in mac and I believe the person submitting the pr develops in windows. What causes this and is there a quick fix?

Comment: This is probably a line endings issue.  Windows line ending is `\r\n` while Mac is just `\n`.  You should research on this topic because it is well covered already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: hi thank you for the info. I have tried a few key words like "github pull request all red" and did not find anything.

Comment: I will look into line ending problems

Comment: There is a way to tell your local Git to preserve the original line endings coming from the server.  Had you done this, the above diff would probably go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a way to tell your local Git to preserve the original line endings coming from the server.

The problem with this is:

- the diff is done on the remote side.
  Even if your *local* config has done a `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, you would still see this issue.
- the diff is done between your remote code and a pull request, submitted (with the wrong eol) by someone else: he/she needs to [fix the sources eol](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings), and push again the same PR to update it.

That being said, when looking at a diff on GitHub, you can ask to [ignore whitespace changes](https://blog.github.com/2011-10-21-github-secrets/#whitespace):  Add `?w=1` to the URL to see the diff with whitespace ignored.
(Since [May 2018, you actually have a diff setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755490/6309))